# JMeter - How to insert JavascriptExecutor into WebDriver Sampler code in Java

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have the following method in the WebDriver code:

```
public String getLastMessage() throws Exception
{
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    String jsexec = "return app.webSocketRouter.lastMessage";
    Object obj1 = js.executeScript(jsexec);
    System.out.println(obj1.toString());
    return obj1.toString();
}
```

How to translate JavascriptExecutor inside the JMeter WebDriver Sampler?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as simple as:

```
var lastMessage = WDS.browser.executeScript('return app.webSocketRouter.lastMessage')
WDS.log.info('lastMessage is: ' + lastMessage)
```

the above code snipped will execute the JavaScript and print the result into *jmeter.log* file.

See [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for more details.

Comment: Can I mix Java and JavaScript if the selected script language is Java?

Comment: You can mix both languages in both directions, see [Java 8 Nashorn Tutorial](http://winterbe.com/posts/2014/04/05/java8-nashorn-tutorial/) for examples. Also be aware that selecting `java` as the language doesn't actually mean `java`, it will be `beanshell` or `bsh` so if you don't like JavaScript - go for `groovy` option or stick to Java 5 language level while developing your code as modern features won't be available. See [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for more details.

Comment: When I insert and run  var lastMessage = WDS.browser.executeScript('return app.webSocketRouter.lastMessage');
WDS.log.info('lastMessage is: ' + lastMessage);  in the WebDriver Sampler, I get error message: Response message: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import ja . . . '' Token Parsing Error: Lexical error at line 35, column 47.  Encountered: "e" (101), after : "\'r": <at unknown location>
 in <unknown file>

Comment: There is a syntax error in your script, that's all what I can state without seeing the code

Comment: JavaScript gives error in Java. It fails on the first ' in the var lastMessage = WDS.browser.executeScript('return app.webSocketRouter.lastMessage').  When I use ", it gives error:Error in method invocation: Method executeScript( java.lang.String ) not found in class'org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver': at Line: 35 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.openqa.selenium.*; import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*; import ja . . . '' : WDS .browser .executeScript ( "return app.webSocketRouter.lastMessage" ). It is because  var lastMessage is not recognized as valid Java data type.